# Kivy osc running server and gui on Android simultaneous

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, osc

I want to run a simulation server and a GUI that responds to the messages of- and influences the server through messages on Android with Kivy and osc.

## Question

Basically my problem comes down to: I can't run both scripts at the same time. How do I do this?

- The GUI: https://github.com/PdeRooij/DMAS/blob/GUI/main.py
- The server: https://github.com/PdeRooij/DMAS/blob/GUI/service/main.py#L55-L114

Relevant code GUI:

```
def start_service(self):
    if platform == 'android':
        from android import AndroidService
        service = AndroidService('Agent emergence service', 'running')
        service.start('service started')
        self.service = service
```

If I build it with buildozer, only the GUI runs. In Ubuntu I would just open 2 terminals and run: `python model/main.py` and `python main.py`. How can I also let model/main.py run in the android .apk?

I think I should do something with: `def start_service(self):`, but I don't know what. Also for some reason PyCharm underlines this in red: `from android import AndroidService`.

### Example that didn't work for me on Android

https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc

### Specs

- Python 2.7.6
- Ubuntu 14.04
- PPA: Kivy-daily

Answer (score 2):

The problem lays in that AndroidService looks for service/main.py. So renaming the folder 'model' to 'service' did the trick.

Interesting to know is that the service doesn't need to have any Kivy code in it. 'from kivy.lib import osc' can be replaced for 'import osc' (which is copied from kivy, but all dependencies removed/replaced).
https://github.com/PdeRooij/DMAS/tree/GUI/service/osc